# How can I reliably replace "you" with "me" or "I" when changing the perspective of dialogue?

Tags: java, string, nlp

Using Java, I would like to take sentences like this:

> **I** will take **you** to the park because **you** asked nicely.

Into this:

> **You** will take **me** to the park because **I** asked nicely.

Converting "I" to "you" is simple enough, but how can I handle "you" turning into "me" or "I"? Is there a reliable way to detect if "you" is acting as an object or a subject? Perhaps someone can suggest a library that does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem. You will have to use NLP (Natural Language Processing). As far as libraries, there are a few options:

- [Apache OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/)
- [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/)
- [Stanford NLP software](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/index.shtml)
- [LingPipe](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/)

Comment: Thanks, can you recommend any of these over the others?